# Problem after starting the game, nothing happens when I click Bulbasaur, Squirtle, or Charmander

Tags: pokemon-go

I started Pokemon Go yesterday and have had the same problem since. The professor gives me pokeballs and then screen appears of my avatar and 3 Pokemon (Bulbasaur, Charamander, Squirtle). But when I click any of the Pokemon nothing happens. Any suggestion?

Comment: you misclicked, you're lagging, servers are lagging

Comment: I cant understand